# Slow bigram frequency function in R

Tags: r, text, frequency

I’m working with Twitter data and I’m currently trying to find frequencies of bigrams in which the first word is “the”. I’ve written a function which seems to be doing what I want but is extremely slow (originally I wanted to see frequencies of all bigrams but I gave up because of the speed). Is there a faster way of solving this problem? I’ve heard about the RWeka package, but have trouble installing it, I get an error about (ERROR: dependencies ‘RWekajars’, ‘rJava’ are not available for package ‘RWeka’)…

```
required libraries: tau and tcltk

bigramThe <- function(dataset,column) {
    bidata <- data.frame(x= character(0), y= numeric(0))
    pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "progress bar", min = 0,max = nrow(dataset), width = 300)
    for (i in 1:nrow(dataset)) {
        a <- column[i]
        bi<-textcnt(a, n = 2, method = "string")
        tweetbi <- data.frame(V1 = as.vector(names(bi)), V2 = as.numeric(bi))
        tweetbi$grepl<-grepl("the ",tweetbi$V1)
        tweetbi<-tweetbi[which(tweetbi$grepl==TRUE),]
        bidata <- rbind(bidata, tweetbi)
        setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label=paste( round(i/nrow(dataset), 0), "% done"))}
    aggbi<-aggregate(bidata$V2, by=list(bidata $V1), FUN=sum)
    close(pb)
    return(aggbi)
}
```

I have almost 500,000 rows of tweets stored in a column that I pass to the function. An example dataset would look like this:

```
text                userid

tweet text 1           1
tweets text 2          2
the tweet text 3       3
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `RWeka`, first run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk` (or install/re-install your JDK in Windows GUI) then try re-installing the package.

Should that fail, use `download.file` to download the source `.zip` file and install from source, i.e. `install.packages("RWeka.zip", type = "source", repos = NULL)`.

If you want to speed things up without using a different package, consider using `multicore` and re-writing the code to use an `apply` function which can take advantage of parallelism.

Comment: I've tried this but was still getting errors - the problem was rJava, eventually this worked: install.packages("rJava", type="mac.binary")

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you have any trouble with installing packages like that then 99% of the time you can solve it by installing from source. install.packages("Master.zip", type= "source", repos = NULL)

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the evil loop structure by collapsing the text column into one long string:

```
paste(dataset[[column]], collapse=" *** ")
bi<-textcnt(a, n = 2, method = "string")
```

I expected to also need 
    subset(bi, function(x) !grepl("***", x)

But it turns out that the textcnt method doesn't include bigrams with *** in them, so you're good to go.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I implemented this with RWeka but it's still running slow, I'm not sure whether the speed can be improved any further.

Comment: This is my current version (sorry about formatting, I indented 4 spaces but it doesn’t seem to work):
    bigramThe3 <- function(dataset,column) {
    a<-paste(column, collapse=" *** ")
    BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
    bi<-BigramTokenizer(a)
    bi<-subset(bi, !grepl("\\*", bi))
    bi<-subset(bi, grepl(“the “, bi))
    tweetbi <- data.frame(V1 = as.vector(bi), V2 = 1)
    aggbi<-aggregate(tweetbi$V2, by=list(tweetbi$V1), FUN=sum)
    return(aggbi)
    }